# Multiple detail sections on a form

Tags: vba, ms-access

ACCESS 2010, windows 7

Is it possible to have multiple detail sections on a form each with a different record source (Different query for each section). If so, how is it done?

Thanks

jpl

Comment: Not in the way you described.  Consider a subform for the other record source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one detail section only, but several subforms.